# ToString() and AddString() method without using .Net Collections

Tags: c#, interview-questions

I was asked to answer the following question before setting up a phone interview, but they said my code wasn't detailed enough.

Question:

> Without using any of the .NET Collection or Linq libraries (i.e.
>   without using List), implement a ListOfStrings object that
>   contains a set of strings. This object has the following methods:
>   Add(string) - inserts a string to the end of the list ToString() -
>   Returns the list as a comma separated string.
>
> Example Usage:
>
> ```
> ListOfStrings list = new ListOfStrings(); // set is empty
> list.Add("abc"); // set is "abc"
> list.Add("xyz"); // set is now "abc", "xyz"
> list.Add("123"); // set is now abc", "xyz", "123"
> list.ToString(); // Should return "abc,xyz,123"
> ```
>
> Ideally, this code should be able to handle large numbers of items.

Answer:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ListOfStrings ls = new ListOfStrings();
                ls.Add("test1");
                ls.Add("test2");
                ls.Add("122");
                ls.Add("");
                ls.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(ls.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class ListOfStrings
    {
        private string ListOfString;

        public ListOfStrings()
        {
            ListOfString = null;
        }
        public string Add(string input)
        {
            if (input != string.Empty)
            {
                ListOfString = ListOfString == null ? input : ListOfString + "," + input;
            }
            return ListOfString;
        }        

        public string ToString()
        {
            return ListOfString;
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know feedback on the code.

Comment: What did they mean by "not detailed enough"? They were expecting comments or something?

Comment: I would suggest reading the question again.  They're not asking you to store a comma separated string.  My best guess is they were looking for you to use an array or create your own collection object to store the strings rather than using the inbuilt collections in C#.

Comment: @CarlWinder The specification is not clear enough to determine that. As long as only `Add` and `ToString` are required using `StringBuilder` is simple and efficient. If we really need a collection, the simplest approach would be a doubly linked list. If random access is required we'd need a tree.

Comment: @CodesInChaos They specifically ask for a list.  Look at the comments // set is now “abc”, “xyz” NOT  set is now “abc,xyz”. I don't think we will ever see eye to eye on this, I think the spec is quite clear.

Comment: @CarlWinder I agree, it did ask for a "set" of strings, and therefore I would have implemented it using an array. However I would have added some comments to the end of the program noting any assumptions that have been made in answering the question, i.e that there was no requirement for deleting therefore an array was used rather than implementing a linked list structure. That way you are showing you took the requirements into consideration in choosing the solution you did, and didnt simply miss or ignore a key point.

Comment: @GavinCoates I'd consider an array a built in .NET Collection, thus violating the requirement. Without that requirement I'd prefer an array or the array based `List<T>` over a linked list as wll.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Actually according to the [.net definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx) a collection is dynamic therefore an array isn't a collection.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think the purpose of the question is to make the user implement functionality similar to the List<T> class, by creating functions that manipulate the data stored. The restriction is there to prevent them from just using the collections classes, and creating an Add() function that just wraps the List.Add() function, but instead implement the logic themselves. Therefore using an array would not violate this. To be clear, I am referring to String[] arrays, NOT the Array() class, which would be cheating.

Comment: @tinstaafl An array implements `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>`, so claiming it's not a collection is dubious IMO. There are also various immutable and readonly collections. The .net parts of MSDN are generally pretty low quality and contain a number of dubious claims like this.

Comment: @GavinCoates, Of course, the requirements also say "set," so I would consider the possibility of `Set` functionality (ie, no duplicates). Mentioning that in the comments about assumptions made would be important, IMO, though.

Answer (score 20):

1. `ListOfString = null;` is useless, fields get initialized to `default(T)` which is `null` for reference types. So you can drop the constructor.

   For simple initializations you can use inline initializers. e.g.

   ```
   private string ListOfString = "";
   ```
2. You're hiding `ToString()` instead of overriding it.
3. You're ignoring empty input strings, the spec doesn't require that. Curiously you're not ignoring `null` input strings.
4. Using a `string` as accumulator leads to quadratic runtime since it has to create a new string which contains all current data for each append.

   Use `StringBuilder.Append` in `Add` instead. Don't return a string from `Add`, else you lose the performance advantage. Call `stringBuilder.ToString()` in your `ToString` operation. This has linear runtime.
5. You're returning `null` if no value has ever been added. I'd expect the empty string instead.

I don't know what they meant by calling your code "not detailed enough". You could add documentation for corner cases, possibly in the form of unit tests. For my observations 3 and 5 it's not clear if your code is behaving like you intended. Documentation and/or unit tests would have clarified your intent.

Comment: +1 for `StringBuilder`... and everything else - nice answer you've got here.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have too much experience with C#, so just some notes about the algorithm/structure. (Maybe there are C#-related issues which I'm not aware of.)

At first I was expecting some array manipulation logic here with extending the array if it's full. They might be expected the same but your solution is quite cool, why would you complicate it? [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) and it's a really simple solution which could work. I have to say that I really like it. Maybe a few (selft-checking) unit tests would have helped you to get a better impression.

A few minor notes:

1. It was not a requirement to ignore empty strings.
2. `Add` could be `void`.
3. The first line seems unnecessary here:

   > ```
   > ls.ToString();
   > Console.WriteLine(ls.ToString());
   > ```

Comment: I would take the fact that they actively said to not use any of the .NET Collections to mean that I wouldn't be allowed to use an array either, as that has been appended with extension methods with LINQ. Although, if you remove that reference, I could possibly see using the purest form of array. Though I wouldn't want to risk that.

Answer (score 4):

Well... I think you answered the question as simple as possible.
If this was a jobinterview, and you did not get the job, you should think "Hooray" - that company does not accept the simple solution, and I am not working there! :)

That said, I would not have submitted the code with the while(true) thing. And maybe I would have initilized to "" and not null.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the question is badly worded, and/or that your answer is too clever and simple for their question, and that instead they wanted a class which implements a list.

Something like:

```
public class ListOfStrings
{
    class Node
    {
        internal Node(string stringValue) { this.stringValue = stringValue; }
        internal readonly string stringValue;
        internal Node nextNode;
    }

    Node firstNode;

    public string Add(string input)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(stringValue)
        if (firstNode == null)
        {
            firstNode = newNode;
            return;
        }
        Node lastNode = firstNode;
        while (lastNode.nextNode != null)
            lastNode = lastNode.nextNode;
        lastNode.nextNode = newNode;
    }
```

In order to "Ideally, this code should be able to handle large numbers of items" you would want to store lastNode as well as firstNode as members (so that you don't need to recalculate lastNode every time you add a new string).

There's some ambiguity when they talk about a 'set' of strings; perhaps they want to keep the strings unique.

---

> Also, I'd like to see what your ToString() would look like.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (firstNode != null)
    {
        sb.Append(firstNode.stringValue);
        // next strings if any are comma-delimited
        for (Node nextNode = firstNode.nextNode; nextNode != null; nextNode = nextNode.nextNode)
        {
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(nextNode.stringValue);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The above returns an empty string if there are no nodes/strings in the list. Alternatively you might want to return `null` so that the user can distinguish between an empty list, and  list which contains one empty string.

OTOH this storage/display format is already sightly ambiguous, e.g. if a string contains a comma when it's stored.

Comment: Good Answer. I suspect from the interview question that they want to have the programmer create a linked list, which is IMO is a good interview question

Comment: If you're not going to have a `lastNode` field, there's no need to even have a `Node` class -- just store your `stringValue` directly in `ListOfStrings`. Also, Id like to see what your `ToString()` would look like.

Comment: @Gabe I updated my answer per your comment.

Comment: @PhilVallone I think it's a really bad question if they actually expect that, but don't have anything in the requirements that forces you to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm compelled to write an answer because no one has really covered the `set` thing yet.  Sets, maps, queues, vectors, linked lists, etc are words that have meaning to programmers, and I have a hard time believing a programmer would ask a question like this without intending the elements be unique.

Overall, I agree with ChrisW and Carl Winder...it looks like they wanted some underlying data structure, not just a `String` that you append to.  And they don't want .Net collections or Linq to be used.

Technically, you could use a `String[] arr` and be safe.  However, adding a new item requires you to create a new array, copy all the old values in, and add in the newest value at the end.  That's fairly expensive and will not work well with large sets.

Extending ChrisW's code:

```
class ListOfStrings
{
    class Node
    {
        internal Node(string stringValue) { this.stringValue = stringValue; }
        internal readonly string stringValue;
        internal Node nextNode;
    }
    Node firstNode;
    Node lastNode;

    public ListOfStrings() { }

    public void Add(String str)
    {
        if (str != null && !Exists(str))
        {
            if (firstNode == null)
            {
                firstNode = new Node(str);
                lastNode = firstNode;
            }
            else
            {
                Node n = new Node(str);
                lastNode.nextNode = n;
                lastNode = n;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool Exists(String str)
    {
        bool result = false;

        Node curr = firstNode;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            if(curr.stringValue.Equals(str))
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            curr = curr.nextNode;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");

        Node curr = firstNode;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            if (result.ToString().Equals(""))
                result.Append(curr.stringValue);
            else
                result.Append(String.Format(",{0}", curr.stringValue));
            curr = curr.nextNode;
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

As you see, I used his `Node` verbatim, and added the `lastNode` like he recommended.  Most importantly, I added `Exists`, which is scoped as private, and put in the `ToString` as well.

Some important notes:

- I added the `override` keyword to `ToString`.  Without doing so, you should get a compiler warning saying you're hiding object.ToString().  Heed these kinds of warnings, regardless of language!  My rule of thumb is to eliminate most, if not all, warnings.
- `ToString` uses a `StringBuilder` as well as `String.Format`.  I did this because `String` is immutable, and doing assignments to `String` essentially destroys the `String` and remakes it - just like the `String[] arr` explanation above.
- `Add` returns nothing.  Typically, `setter`-type functions don't return a value.  If they do, it's almost always a boolean which states whether the operation was a success or not.
- `Exists` guarantees uniqueness.  It is case sensitive, so elements `"XYZ"` and `"xyz"` can exist at the same time.  Making new functions that aren't specified in the question can be beneficial: it shows the interviewer that you can break new functionality out into a separate method, which makes the code easier to read and maintain.  It also shows you can scope new functions properly.  The outside world, according to the problem, doesn't use `Exists`, so there's no reason to make it public or protected.  This is a very minor detail, but sometimes it's the little things which make the biggest difference.
- `Add` protects against adding `null` values, but it does not protect against adding the empty string: `""`, since the spec didn't cover whether to ignore that or not.

Comment: +1 but unfortunately that implementation of `Exists` is expensive i.e. O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: @ChrisW That's true, but without using some form of well-balanced tree structure you're essentially choosing which operations are O(n) and which are O(1).  For an interview question, I don't think I would start with that kind of answer.  It takes longer, and it's a good talking point if they proceed further with interviewing.  Ie, "How would you improve this?" "I would ...."

Comment: If the type was really meant to be a set, why would they call it `ListOfStrings` and not `SetOfStrings`?

Comment: @svick Well, the two aren't mutually exclusive.  You could have a vector set, a queue set, a circular buffer set, etc.